# This code for inserting variables into a mysql db as rows doesn't work (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get variables to input as rows to columns in a mysql database (I'm new to both mysql and php) via php. However, it doesn't seem to work and this test code I put in fails every time. Again I'm new to this, so if I'm making a stupid mistake please point it out nicely.

```
$conn = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "testdb");
echo "Database connection successful";
echo '<br />';
$test1 = "a";
$test2 = "a";
$test3 = "a";
$test4 = "a";
$test5 = "a";
$query = "INSERT INTO testtable (testcolumn1, testcolumn2, testcolumn3, testcolumn4, testcolumn5) VALUES ('$test1', '$test2', '$test3', '$test4', '$test5')";
if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
    echo "passed";
} else {
    echo "failed";
}
```

The database and table and columns are all valid and present, it's something to do with how I'm using the query. Can anyone help?

Comment: you have 6 fields in your query, but only 5 values

Comment: Oh... should have noticed that, but it still fails even after fixing that.

Comment: try: use BACKTICKS arround the name table ``` - table is reserved word

Comment: Still doesn't fix it.

Comment: see my answer with sample

Comment: I changed the table name (and added a new table and columns, obviously) to avoid any problems with that (still fails)

Comment: remove the ; in the query to : .....'$test4', '$test5')";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script seems to be working fine. I was able to execute the following script without a problem.

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli ("localhost", "newuser", "password", "testdb");
echo "Database connection successful";
echo '<br />';
$test1 = "a";
$test2 = "a";
$test3 = "a";
$test4 = "a";
$test5 = "a";
$query = "INSERT INTO testtable (testcolumn1, testcolumn2, testcolumn3, testcolumn4, testcolumn5) VALUES ('$test1', '$test2', '$test3', '$test4', '$test5');";
if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
    echo "passed";
} else {
    echo "failed";
}
```

Double check your Database connection.

Comment: Tried that, still prints out failed and nothing in DB.

Comment: There is no real error message, just my testing code prints out "failed" and nothing shows up in the database.

Comment: can u share the output of the sql query : ` show create table table-name ` https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/show-create-table/

Comment: Huh, I just ran your code locally (with my db) and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [bb]> insert into table (val) VALUES(99);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'table (val) VALUES(99)' at line 1

MariaDB [bb]> insert into `table` (val) VALUES(99);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bb]>
```

**and your query:**

you can copy it

```
INSERT INTO `table` (testcolumn1, testcolumn2, testcolumn3, testcolumn4, testcolumn5) VALUES ('$test1', '$test2', '$test3', '$test4', '$test5')
```

Comment: As stated below, no specific error that I can see- my code prints out failed and nothing shows up in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

can you try the below code, and another thing just asking did you checked the auto increment field of primary key.

```
    $conn = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "testdb");
    if(!$conn){
       echo "Database connection failed";
    } else {
       echo "Database connection successful";
        echo '<br />';
        $test1 = "a";
        $test2 = "a";
        $test3 = "a";
        $test4 = "a";
        $test5 = "a";


       $query = "INSERT INTO testtable (testcolumn1, testcolumn2,    testcolumn3, testcolumn4, testcolumn5)
        VALUES ('$test1', '$test2', '$test3', '$test4', '$test5');";
      if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
        echo "passed";
      } else {
      echo "failed";
   }
}
```